# Paging with html sites / UI View?

Tags: iphone, html, sdk, controls

as a xcode beginner I'm just wondering if it's possible to swipe html sites in a uiwebview?
the idea is, to have several html sites (with nice design) which the user can flip through without tapping a button.

i know 2-way-iScroll by cubiq and thought it might be able to do it native...?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this PageControl sample project (for iPhone and iPad):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

You can simply put a UIWebView in the content view.

Comment: yes, thanks. but i didn't get that working. In the content_iPhone.plist I inserted instead of xy.png now xy.html and insertet the xy.html file in the folder Resources/PhoneContent/SmallImages.